# Why does my own payment method not get disabled?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

I have created a payment method module in Magento 2.4.4 after a lot of trial and error and I finally have a small working version that works both in the adminhtml and the frontend.

The problem I have is that when I set it as "Enabled" > "No", it still appears in the checkout page and the observers are still running.

I looked through other answers, like [this one from in here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145455/enable-and-disable-payment-method-in-magento-2) and I seem to have my own XML structured correctly.

What exactly is the trigger point/code for Magento to enable/disable a payment method so that I am able to debug this?

Edit: Here is the code requested:

#### registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Test_Testpayment',
    __DIR__
);
```

#### etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noTestSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Test_Testpayment" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

#### etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Store/etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <payment>
            <testpayment>
                <payment_action>authorize</payment_action><!-- You can use another methor like capture  -->
                <model>Test\Testpayment\Model\PaymentMethod</model>
                <active>1</active>
                <title>Test Payment</title>
                <order_status>pending_payment</order_status><!-- set default order status-->
            </testpayment>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

#### etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="payment">
            <group id="testpayment" translate="label" sortOrder="2" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Test Payment</label>
                <field id="active" translate="label comment" sortOrder="1" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

#### Model/PaymentMethod.php

```
<?php

namespace Test\Testpayment\Model;
class PaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{
    protected $_code = 'testpayment';
    public function authorize( \Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount ) 
    {
        return $this;
    }
}
```

#### view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="testpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Test_Testpayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="testpayment" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

#### view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/testpayment.js

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Test_Testpayment/payment/testpayment'
            }
        });
    }
);
```

#### view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer.js

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'testpayment',
                component: 'Test_Testpayment/js/view/payment/method-renderer/testpayment'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

#### view/frontned/web/template/payment/testpayment.html

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the code by editing the question?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I have attached the relevant code. It's an absolute basic payment method that does nothing, yet I can't figure out the basics of Magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never managed to actually figure out what caused this but it is fixed.

I despise the naming "conventions" of magento where the directory has Pascalcase, then the module registration has lowercase and then some files required Pascal+Snake case.

I decided to rename my folders and remove Pascal Case and it now works. Within this smorgasbord of different naming conventions, a typo occurred, obviously as expected.