# Why is the Magento AbstractMethod class throws an error when I use Dependency injection on my own class that extends it?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.4, magento2.4.4

I have a simple payment method module.

I have successfully used Dependency Injection on both the 2 Controllers I have for 2 new Routes and on my Observer where I grab some data from the config.

BUT, I have been having an issue with my payment method not disabling which is [still open here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/371030/why-does-my-own-payment-method-not-get-disabled), and now I'm in the process of fixing that.

One solution I found is to implement my own `isAvailable()` method which works for hardcoded Boolean values, but obviously I need to check if the config value is yes or no and return true or false accordingly, but when I do this, I get the error:

```
Error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in /var/www/html/app/code/Magento/Payment/Model/Method/AbstractMethod.php:736
```

Which is the return line on this one:

```
    public function getConfigData($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        if ('order_place_redirect_url' === $field) {
            return $this->getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl();
        }
        if (null === $storeId) {
            $storeId = $this->getStore();
        }
        $path = 'payment/' . $this->getCode() . '/' . $field;
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue($path, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
    }
```

[Here is the screenshot.](https://i.imgur.com/trySwU4.png)

When I inject my own Helper class, which works fine everywhere else in my module, within my `PaymentModel.php` it breaks the AbstractMethod class that I extend? How is that related?

Why would `scopeConfig` would be null but only when I inject it in another class?

I obviously run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and `cache: clean` every time I change it.

Answer (score 0):

Solution never found.

I just resorted to using another solution for my issue.

Extending the AbstractMethod class and using Dependency injection in my own payment method class, still to this day, breaks the AbstractMethod class itself.